# Animate a line drawing as an extension of another line with plotly.js

Tags: plotly.js

I have been working on this issue for some time and cannot find a correct solution.

Here a pen https://codepen.io/jean2607/pen/bXKPXz?editors=0010
with some code

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4], layout).then(function() {
    Plotly.animate('myDiv', frames, {
        transition: {
            duration: 0
        },
        frame: {
            duration: 1,
            redraw: false
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to animate only the green "dashdot line" corresponding to trace 4 but impossible so far...
I must be doing something wrong, but I can't see what it is !

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution that meets my needs 
There was still a small error in the preparation of the data for the target trace but it is especially with this piece of code that everything works well now.
If someone finds something more appropriate, even better!

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [trace6, trace2], layout, options)
.then(function() {
    Plotly.addTraces('myDiv', trace1);
})
.then(function() {
    Plotly.addTraces('myDiv', trace4);
})
.then(function() {
    Plotly.addTraces('myDiv', trace5);
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('top!');
    Plotly.animate('myDiv', frames, {
        transition: {
            duration: 0
        },
        frame: {
            duration: 1,
            redraw: false
        }
    });
})
```